A rational matrix $A$ has an inverse of integer entries
I encounter a matrix $A$ that looks like this
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1&\dfrac12&\cdots&\dfrac1n\\
\dfrac12&\dfrac13&\cdots&\dfrac1{n+1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
\dfrac1n&\dfrac1{n+1}&\cdots&\dfrac1{2n-1}\end{matrix}\right].$$
As it is obvious that $A$ has an inverse $A^{-1}$, I am curious whether $A^{-1}$ has integer entries for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. What I know is that this is true for $n=2,3,4$, but nothing more.

This is called the Hilbert matrix and its inverse is known in closed form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix
